# How to do a pop-up window with textfields in Objective-C?

Tags: objective-c, popup, modal-dialog, uialertview

In the iPhone Objective-C app, I want to pop-up a window (which is smaller than the main view, and the app does not stop running) when a button is tapped, with textField for the user to input text, and dismiss it when it is done. 
This is widely used but I really cannot google the relevant content out.
What view should I use to connect it with the button? AlertView (which seems you cannot add dialogue in), ModalView?
Are there relevant info somewhere?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Make the popup it's own, full-sized window. Put a UIImageView in behind your popup screen, and duplicate the results of the normal window. That way, it will look like a popup window, but it still has the proper animation speed and everything. If you do it as a real popup, the game itself will slow down and look jumpy.

Answer (score 0):

You can create any view and use `UIViewController`'s `presentModalViewController:` to display a modal view controller (and even animate it).

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But modalview normally covers the full screen. What i like is the pop-up view like Facebook login and publish window on many games, a bit smaller than the screen and show a bit of greyed out background underneath.